# Center floating divs when resizing

Tags: html, css

How do I center an unordered list of tables so that when the window is resized, the list is still centered.  This list moves the next table to the next line when it cannot fit anymore.  Code:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="project-list" class="child">
        <div class="the-crew_item">
            <li>
                <a href="#/got/" class="proj-link">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="proj">
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td>
                                <a href="#/got/" class="proj-link"><img src="images/got-thumb.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td class="project-desc" style="background: url(images/logo-hbo.png) no-repeat center center;">
                                <h1>Game of Thrones</h1>
                                Epic Fan Event
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </a>
            </li></div><div class="the-crew_item">
        <li>
            <a href="#/airbnb/" class="proj-link">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="proj">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>
                            <a href="#/airbnb/" class="proj-link"><img src="images/air-thumb.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="project-desc" style="background: url(images/logo-airbnb.png) no-repeat center center;">
                            <h1>Airbnb</h1>
                            Hello LA
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have added my css, but it complicates things, and it's wrong.  What I need help with is the css.  Please forgive me for that

Comment: We can't help you with just the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you -

```css
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="project-list" class="child">
        <div class="the-crew_item">
            <li>
                <a href="#/got/" class="proj-link">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="proj">
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td>
                                <a href="#/got/" class="proj-link"><img src="images/got-thumb.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td class="project-desc" style="background: url(images/logo-hbo.png) no-repeat center center;">
                                <h1>Game of Thrones</h1>
                                Epic Fan Event
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </a>
            </li></div><div class="the-crew_item">
        <li>
            <a href="#/airbnb/" class="proj-link">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="proj">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>
                            <a href="#/airbnb/" class="proj-link"><img src="images/air-thumb.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="project-desc" style="background: url(images/logo-airbnb.png) no-repeat center center;">
                            <h1>Airbnb</h1>
                            Hello LA
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good start, but I need each table (one for Game of Thrones, one for Airbnb) to be its own separate element so that I could create some sort of grid.  So if the window is resized, it will shift one of the tables, keeping the whole thing centered, rather than the whole container being centered.

Comment: You should look into flexbox, for example if you added the properties 'display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;' to your container div all its children would be arranged in the center of the screen.

Comment: will that work with all browsers?  I'd want my page to work on old browsers too.

Comment: It's not supported on ie8 or ie9 and ie10 only works with prefix of -ms- on the properties. You could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/seanmurrin/7702n7fb/ instead and then use media queries to adjust the li properties depending on the screen width.